# How to run an elevated command prompt through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-studio

I am making a Powershell GUI program so I can easily change audit, and password settings with the click of a button. I already have the code to do this, but it's written in batch and so I run it in cmd using `CMD /C " "`to solve that problem. The new problem is that I need to run CMD in elevated mode to actually perform the code. I am using SAPIEN PowerShell Studio 2017 to create the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are inside the Powershell:

```
Start-Process PowerShell –Verb RunAs
```

or directly from the cmd prompt, you can do like this:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell –Verb RunAs"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would this elevate PowerShell, and would I be able to run CMD in elevated mode if I do this?

Comment: @CamdenLaCassa: Yes , of course. go through the `get-help start-process`. You will get examples on how to open *nonewwindow* and all.

Comment: One of the problems with this is that it is not simply PowerShell, it is a GUI that I am making using PowerShell. I don't need to know how to elevate PowerShell, since I can set the GUI to prompt to run as administrative. I just need to know if I can run cmd in elevated mode using powershell.`

Comment: Yes you can. The same way you can do that.